# Kentico Macro to Get Page Type

Tags: macros, kentico

I'm new to Kentico and am using version 9 for a website.  A graphic designer asked me if I could create a macro or code that adds the page type of a page to the body tag as a css class.  Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following is a macro, that gives you page type info object:

```
{% DocumentContext.CurrentDocument.NodeClass #%}
```

Go to System -> Macros -> Console to see/try available macros.

Answer (score 5):

```
<body class="{% CurrentDocument.NodeClass.ClassName.ToString() #%}">
```

Answer (score 2):

I use Kentico 8.2 version and I can get this using:

```
<body class="anotherClass {% ClassName #%}">...</body>
```

Maybe this work also in Kentico 9.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

```
DocumentContext.CurrentPageInfo.ClassName
```